# Cmake -E tar unzip is corrupt

Tags: cmake, zip

cmake version 3.20

For this zip file:
`http://kakadusoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/KDU805_Demo_Apps_for_Win64_200602.msi_.zip`

When running
`cmake -E tar xvz KDU805_Demo_Apps_for_Win64_200602.msi_.zip`
the msi is only 176 bytes in size : should be around 20 MB.
Is this a known issue for `cmake tar` ?

Comment: brilliant! thank you. Please post as an answer and I will mark as correct

Answer (score 1):

The `z` flag in your command specified that it should be extracted using gzip. Remove that flag.

`cmake -E tar xv KDU805_Demo_Apps_for_Win64_200602.msi_.zip`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Turns out the z wasn't the problem - the msi file was missing.

Comment: hah. thats a problem too